# R dplyr to data table - Group and Filter

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to transform my data manipulation code from `dplyr` to `data.table` for speed reasons. I am almost there but missing the final step.

I have some sample data to replicate my problem.

```
c_dt = data.table(u_id=rep(c("u1", "u2"),each=5),
                  p_id=c("p1", "p1", "p1", "p2","p2", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2" ), 
                  c_dt=c("2015-12-01", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-03", "2015-12-02",
                         "2015-12-05", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-03", "2015-12-04", 
                         "2015-12-05", "2015-12-06"))
```

I wish to identify the rows where `u_id` and `p_id` is duplicated; and keep only the row with the minimum `c_dt` (essentially keep the first instance). I use the following `dplyr` code for this:

```
c_df <- as.data.frame(c_dt)
cdedup_df <- c_df %>% group_by(p_id, u_id) %>% filter(c_dt == min(c_dt))
```

Which give the below output

```
> cdedup_df
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: p_id, u_id

  u_id p_id       c_dt
1   u1   p1 2015-12-01
2   u1   p2 2015-12-02
3   u2   p1 2015-12-02
4   u2   p2 2015-12-03
```

I have the following `data.table` code that correctly identifies the required rows but I am unable to figure out how to just filter and the row as it is.

```
cdedup_dt <- c_dt[,c_dt == min(c_dt),by = list(u_id, p_id)]
cdedup_dt
    u_id p_id    V1
 1:   u1   p1  TRUE
 2:   u1   p1 FALSE
 3:   u1   p1 FALSE
 4:   u1   p2  TRUE
 5:   u1   p2 FALSE
 6:   u2   p1  TRUE
 7:   u2   p2  TRUE
 8:   u2   p2 FALSE
 9:   u2   p2 FALSE
10:   u2   p2 FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below my approach. I would expect it scales better for big dataset, as there is no `min` by `group`, just single sort which data.table makes very efficient and then subset first by group.

```
setorderv(c_dt, "c_dt")[, .SD[1L], .(u_id, p_id)]
# in data.table 1.9.7+ you can also use `head`
setorderv(c_dt, "c_dt")[, head(.SD, 1L), .(u_id, p_id)]
```

Below code includes validation of current other answers.
If OP will provide big dataset I can add benchmarks.

```
library(data.table)
c_dt = data.table(u_id=rep(c("u1", "u2"),each=5), p_id=c("p1", "p1", "p1", "p2","p2", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2" ), c_dt=c("2015-12-01", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-03", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-05", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-03", "2015-12-04", "2015-12-05", "2015-12-06"))

zero = c_dt[, list(c_dt=min(c_dt)), by=list(u_id, p_id)]
ananda = c_dt[, list(c_dt = c_dt[c_dt == min(c_dt)]), by = .(u_id, p_id)]
tal = c_dt[, .SD[rank(c_dt, ties.method = c("first")) == 1],by = .(u_id, p_id)]
all.equal(zero, ananda)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(ananda, tal)
#[1] TRUE

jan = setorderv(c_dt, "c_dt")[, .SD[1L], .(u_id, p_id)]
all.equal(tal, jan)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: A quick and dirty benchmark I performed on my machine shows that @zero323 method is the most efficient. Can you please give a short explanation of what is actually going on in your command? Is it some sort of a join operation?

Comment: @TalJ.Levy yes, `setorderv` sorts data set. What is the volume you are testing?

Comment: I was using 9000 different values of `u_id`, `p_id` and `c_dt`. Dataset size was 20,000,000 rows (which of course means I add duplicates).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
c_dt[, list(c_dt=min(c_dt)), by=list(u_id, p_id)]
##    u_id p_id       c_dt
## 1:   u1   p1 2015-12-01
## 2:   u1   p2 2015-12-02
## 3:   u2   p1 2015-12-02
## 4:   u2   p2 2015-12-03
```

Comment: Or maybe `c_dt[, list(c_dt = c_dt[c_dt == min(c_dt)]), by = .(u_id, p_id)]`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I wasn't sure about it. Description of the problem (_essentially keep the first instance_) doesn't match example code.

Comment: @zero323, can you please explain what is the meaning of putting a list in the *j* column (which holds the minimum of c_dt for every unique pair of u_id and p_id)?

Comment: In general `dt[, list(v)]` (or `dt[, .(v)]`) indicates that return type is a data.table. `dt[,v]` returns a vector. When you use by it is no longer obvious though. – zero323 2 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

So indeed you are very close. All you were missing is to pass `.SD` in the *j* column. Let's see how is works:

```
library(data.table)
c_dt = data.table(u_id=rep(c("u1", "u2"),each=5),  
                  p_id=c("p1", "p1", "p1", "p2","p2", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2" ), 
                  c_dt=c("2015-12-01", "2015-12-02",  
                   "2015-12-03", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-05", 
                   "2015-12-02", "2015-12-03", "2015-12-04", 
                   "2015-12-05", "2015-12-06"))
c_dt
    u_id p_id       c_dt
 1:   u1   p1 2015-12-01
 2:   u1   p1 2015-12-02
 3:   u1   p1 2015-12-03
 4:   u1   p2 2015-12-02
 5:   u1   p2 2015-12-05
 6:   u2   p1 2015-12-02
 7:   u2   p2 2015-12-03
 8:   u2   p2 2015-12-04
 9:   u2   p2 2015-12-05
10:   u2   p2 2015-12-06
```

Now we will group **by** *u_id* and *p_id* and filter by the minimum value of *c_df*:

```
cdedup_dt <- c_dt[ , .SD[c_dt == min(c_dt)], by = .(u_id, p_id)]
cdedup_dt
   u_id p_id       c_dt
1:   u1   p1 2015-12-01
2:   u1   p2 2015-12-02
3:   u2   p1 2015-12-02
4:   u2   p2 2015-12-03
```

Note that `.(u_id, p_id)` is equal to `list(u_id, p_id)` and `.SD` refers to the Subset of the Data.table for each group. All you were missing is that `.SD`.
As mentioned by @zero323 **min** will keep duplicates (which basically means that we have some duplicate rows in our example). If you only wish to keep one record for each group a safer bet will be to use the rank function:

```
cdedup_dt <- c_dt[, .SD[rank(c_dt, ties.method = c("first")) == 1],by = .(u_id, p_id)]

cdedup_dt
   u_id p_id       c_dt
1:   u1   p1 2015-12-01
2:   u1   p2 2015-12-02
3:   u2   p1 2015-12-02
4:   u2   p2 2015-12-03
```